# http and https protocol

Tags: c++, qt, https, network-programming

I write a simple web server. At this stage I had already written requests will support protocol http. Now I want to add https.

Here is a resource from which I took as an [example http server](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtservice/qtservice-example-server.html).
Here I look at the [example https server](http://docs.huihoo.com/qt/solutions/4/qtsslsocket/server-example.html).

As you can see all the keys and certificates is established immediately . But I need to get for each site they were different . Correspondingly, they should be set after the header processing .
Also with the example number 1 that inherit from HttpDaemon QTcpServer. And with Example 2 SSLServer inherit from QTcpServer. Both have a method void incomingConnection (int). So I can not understand how my server determined use https or http ( The answer probably lies in the method paramatre incomingConnection? In the example it is int, and the second quint16. But I doubt it. )

I need you to different sites running on my server had different https certificate. And at the same time to work with them on sites http.

Comment: You do know that HTTP commonly runs on port 80 and HTTPS commonly on port 443? It's quite possible that your server cannot distinguish the two, but relies on standard port numbers to tell them apart. Try running both on port 9999 and see if it still works.

Comment: @MSalters Ok ... I run 80 http server, and the server https on port 443. But this only solves part of the problem, because different sites must have different certificates. And in this case it will be one.